# Search a specific word from Text Js , Including Special Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, keyword

I have an Array which I loop through extracting word by word and comparing them to find any matches in a large text.

```
  var myString="I know the languages  C, C# and JAVA"
  var languages=['JAVA','C','Angular','C++','Python','C#'];
  for (var i=0;i<languages.length;i++){
      var myPattern = new RegExp('(\\w*'+languages[i]+'\\w*)','gi');
      var matches = myString.match(myPattern);
      if (matches != null)
      {
          console.log(languages[i]);
      }
  }
```

The Regex throws an Error when I reach C# or C++?
Anything to extract both of these as well as others would be Appreciated.
*Note* I Still need to escape other special characters such as (',','.','|');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex, that's a simple `indexOf` operation, with even "better" results than the regex - e.g. you could also indicate where the string was found in the text.

```js
const myString="I know the languages  C, C# and JAVA";
const languages=['JAVA','C','Angular','C++','Python','C#'];

languages.forEach(lang => {
  let x;
  if ((x = myString.indexOf(lang)) > -1) {
    console.log(`Found ${lang} at position ${x}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use String `includes()` Method. The `includes()` method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string. This method returns `true` if the string contains the characters, and `false` if not. Note that this method is `case sensitive`.

```js
var myString = 'I know the languages  C, C# and JAVA',
    languages = [ 'JAVA','C','Angular','C++','Python','C#' ];

for ( var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++ ) {
    if ( myString.includes( languages[ i ] ) ) console.log( languages[ i ] )
}
```